# How does NaF protect G proteins from denaturation?

Tags: biochemistry, cell-signaling

Below is presented Figure 4 from the [1977 paper of Ross and Gilman](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0021-9258(19)66920-6), which provided evidence for the existence of G proteins:

[image: Figure 4 from Gilman and Ross]

The protocol (and rationale) is as follows:

1. Wild-type cell membranes was preincubated at 37˚C for 30min. (This causes loss of adenyl cylase activity, attributed to dissociation from another component — G protein — essential for its activity.)
2. Gpp(NH)p was then added — with a no-addition control — and the membranes further incubated at 50°C for the times shown. (The higher temperature denatures the second component — G protein —but not the adenyl cyclase. Gpp(NH)p had previously been shown to activate adenyl cyclase and was required to assay activity.)
3. The extracts were chilled and mixed with adenyl cyclase-depleted membranes to provide the second component. Adenyl cyclase assays were then carried out with Gpp(NH)p or NaF (which was also known to stimulate adenyl cyclase).

- When incubation was performed in the absence of Gpp(NH)p, and then stimulated with Gpp(NH)p, much of the G protein denatured quickly during incubation, decreasing AC activity
- When incubation was performed in the presence of Gpp(NH)p, and then stimulated with Gpp(NH)p, the G protein showed increased thermal stability, denaturing slower during incubation and decreasing AC activity to a smaller extent
- When incubation was performed without Gpp(NH)p, and stimulated with fluoride, the G proteins showed similar activity to the sample stabilised with Gpp(NH)p, despite no Gpp being present during incubation.

How is the presence of fluoride ion seemingly able to reverse the denaturation of the G protein? How does it allow a level of activity similar to the Gpp(NH)p-stabilised G protein, despite the fact that the G protein was not stabilised during incubation?

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. I have edited the first part of your question, correcting the order of authors, modulating the statement of its significance, and describing the experiment and its rationale. I think your bulleted interpretation is incorrect, but I have retained it in order to present an alternative in my answer.

Comment: Could you tell me why you think my bulleted interpretation is incorrect?

Comment: I am composing an answer — be patient. I am having to read and re-read the original paper and this is taking time.

Comment: The question is whether the authors are really using open circles for two conditions — membranes incubated with and without Gpp(NH)p but assayed in the presence of NaF. It beggars belief. But the text suggests that this is so, contrasting half-lives of 8min and 2min for NaF and Gpp(NH)p with unpreincubated membranes. Not sure you are going to get an answer now. I was attracted by the mechanism of stabilization at the protein level, which is actuall through aluminium fluoride.